# Why does setting CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER in CMakeLists.txt remove it as a cache variable?

Tags: cmake, cmake-cache

The following CMakeLists.txt produces cache variables that includes `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER`, as expected, because in the absence of the variable being explicitly set, CMake will set the value depending on its inspection of the environment:

```
# CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)
project(my_project VERSION 0.1.0)
```

```
$ cmake -B build -LA
...
CMAKE_COLOR_MAKEFILE:BOOL=ON
CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:FILEPATH=/usr/bin/c++
CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_AR:FILEPATH=/usr/bin/gcc-ar-11
CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_RANLIB:FILEPATH=/usr/bin/gcc-ranlib-11
...
```

If I insert a `set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER ...)` statement in the CMakeLists.txt, `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER` disappears as a cache variable:

```
# CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "gcc")
project(my_project VERSION 0.1.0)
```

```
$ cmake -B build -LA
...
CMAKE_COLOR_MAKEFILE:BOOL=ON
CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_AR:FILEPATH=/usr/bin/gcc-ar-11
CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_RANLIB:FILEPATH=/usr/bin/gcc-ranlib-11
...
```

My understanding of CMake local variables and cache variables is that `set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "gcc")` creates a local variable named `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER`. But I've heard it said that doing this will create a shadow variable in the local scope (therefore we have `set(var val)` vs. `set(var val CACHE <type> <docstring>)`). **Why does it have the effect of removing the cache variable altogether?** (I assume that's what its elimination from CMakeCache.txt means)

Comment: If you specify it directly, then cmake doesn't have to go to the trouble of finding and saving that variable.